# Which IDE can refactor (rename) Zend Framework 2 classes properly?

Tags: php, ide, refactoring, zend-framework2, rename

A classname in a zf2 application is scattered around the project in several config/autoload strings, use statements, even template_map keys, whatnot.

Is there **an IDE/plugin** that keeps indexing these occurrences, thus **can reliable refactor** (I mean only rename) **a Zend Framework 2 class**?

Considering the namespaces as well (as I can create classes of the same name under different locations).

Comment: I don't really like this 'string_heavy' stuff in zf anyway, so error prone, wrecks code completion many cases.

Answer (score 2):

NetBEANS WITHOUT a second thought not mention that it wont automatically rename line of code that is mentioned in namespaces etc as it is purely user dependent feature on what they wanna write.

Comment: Yap, really. Actually this is the zf nature then, aw. Seems struggling for me to maintain all those strings forever.

Comment: This is some thing you have to kinda work around it since most of php based frame works are of almost similar nature.

Comment: So sad. I mean I'd really like to create/rename a class anytime, and not hesitating if it worths or not...

Comment: Well there may be some IDE may be i dont know of , which may sort of do automatically it every where but as i have tried Netbeans do it fairly in its power.

Comment: Then it is almost irrelevant what IDE I use (Eclipse/Zend Studio/PhpStorm/NetBeans...)

Comment: then i guess you answered your own question.